# Why a concatenation of gstrings returned from a function is an empty string - Groovy 1.7.4

Tags: windows, macos, groovy, gstring

I have the following code:

```
public class TestGr
{
  static String aaa = "wwww";

  public static void main(args)
  {
    println "["+getAAA()+"]";
    println "[" + getBBB() +"]";
  }

  static String getAAA()
  {
    return ""
    + "${aaa}"
  }

  static String getBBB()
  {
     return "" + "${aaa}" 
  }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
[]
[wwww]
```

I do not understand why in the first call I get an empty string. Does anybody know why a line break change the output of a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the way the groovy is being parsed.  Since semicolons at the end of statements are optional, newlines sometimes make a difference.

getAAA() is being parsed as two statements, like this:

```
static String getAAA() {
    return "";
    +"${aaa}";
}
```

Even though the unary `+` operator doesn't make sense with a string arg, groovy can't catch it due to its dynamic nature.  There might be a `postive()` meta method on string that would make it valid.

EDIT:

For a better idea of what's going on, start up `groovyConsole` and load your script.  Select "Inspect AST" from the Script menu.  You'll see something like this:

[image: AST Browser Image]

Comment: No, even if you drop the optional `return` statement, there's no way I can think of to join the `aaa` string onto the previous statement without doing some complex AST manipulation.  At least dropping the optional `return` makes this throw an error

Comment: thanks for help. I have to say that -- if somebody is not aware of this groovy feature -- it can cause an extremely hard to find bug.